# Accounting for Missing Values Loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops, copy-paste

I have been working on this program that...

1. Finds a five-digit code in a workbook
2. Looks in a second workbook to find a matching code
3. Copies a set of corresponding data from the first workbook onto the second.

It works for the most part, but when there is a value that is present on the first book but not the second it fails.  If I let it run the values get messed up, but the program does complete.  I need to find a way to recognize an error, which would be foundItem = 0, and then restart the loop from that point so nothing gets copied.  I appreciate the help.

```
Sub findExample()
On Error Resume Next
Dim foundItem As Range
Dim codeValue As String
Dim strAddress As String
Dim endOfWorksheet As Boolean
Dim x As Long

x = 1
Do While endOfWorksheet = False
x = x + 1
Sheets("Medex Center Master List").Select
Dim NRange As String
NRange = "N" + CStr(x)
codeValue = Range(NRange, NRange).Value
Sheets("6035P_ATRSDeviceListII").Select
Set foundItem = Range("M1:M300").Find(codeValue)

Dim col
Dim rowa

col = Split(foundItem.Address, "$")(1)
rowa = Split(foundItem.Address, "$")(2)
strAdress = col + rowa

Dim FRange As String
FRange = "A" + CStr(x) + ":" + "M" + CStr(x)
Sheets("Medex Center Master List").Range(FRange).Copy Sheets("6035P_ATRSDeviceListII").Range(strAdress).Offset(0, 1)

If x = 265 Then
endOfWorksheet = True
End If

Loop
MsgBox "program completed"
End Sub
```

Thanks Again,
Samuel

Comment: Get rid of that `On Error Resume Next` first. It's hiding any error that's occurring.

Comment: Next step is to test if the `Find` succeeded. After `Set foundItem = Range("M1:M300").Find(codeValue)`, put `If Not foundItem Is Nothing Then`... make sure to add a closing `End If` after you do the copy several lines later.

Comment: What would I put in that '''If Not FoundItem Is Nothing Then''' loop in order for it to continue properly after the error.  There are values in the spreadsheet that will cause an error, I just need to properly account for it so it doesn't mess up the rest of the program.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments but with more detail:

1. Remove the `On Error Resume Next`. It is just hiding any errors that are occurring.
2. Your code could be simplified and improved in the following manner:

   - Use a regular `For...Next` loop.
   - Avoid using `Select`.
   - Specify more parameters of `Range.Find`, specifically `LookIn` and `LookAt`.
   - Test if the `Find` succeeded using `If Not ... Is Nothing Then`.

```
Sub FindExample()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 to 265
        Dim masterWs As Worksheet
        Set masterWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Medex Center Master List")

        Dim codeValue As String
        codeValue = masterWs.Range("N" & i).Value

        Dim deviceListWs As Worksheet
        Set deviceListWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("6035P_ATRSDeviceListII")

        Dim foundItem As Range
        Set foundItem = deviceListWs.Range("M1:M300").Find( _
            What:=codeValue, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

        If Not foundItem Is Nothing Then
            masterWs.Range("A" & i & ":M" & i).Copy _
                Destination:=foundItem.Offset(0,1)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```